# Cat is not eating like he should

Tags: cats, feeding, diseases

My cat recently stopped eating all of his food and at first I thought it was because he was bored(he was eating the same food for a year) so I got new food and tried to change it slowly but he had no interest. I took him to the vet and she did blood work and urinalysis and everything came out good. The only thing she mentioned at the visit was he has gingivitis in the front little teeth. 
He's 3 years old, neutered, and an indoor only cat. 
Before all this he ate a mix of Fromm chicken dry food and Earthborn wet food. I wanted to transition him to Orijen dry and while he now(after medication) eats some of it he won't eat it all. The only thing he really ate, and I bought it because I was desperate for him to eat, was Sheba canned wet food but that made him have diarrhea. I'm trying to give him Friskies just so he can eat but he only eats a little and that's when I sit with him and coax him to eat it. The vet has him on steroids now and we finished antibiotics a few days ago. I really am at my wits end and I don't know what to do to get him to eat. We traveled kind of far with him recently and I'm not sure if that's the cause but I just wanted to ask if anyone had a similar experience and what they did.

Comment: How is the gingivitis? That could be causing pain and discomfort when he's eating. The key here is to clear that up.

Comment: Well the vet said to hold off on brushing his teeth because the toothpaste might make him not eat more. She felt the tooth and she said it doesn't seem too bad and she said it probably isnt the reason he's not eating. I'm note sure if I should ignore her advice and just brush them anyway...

Comment: That's a hard one, when you say she felt the tooth? That implies a rotten tooth, unless it's very localized gum disease. given her bloods are normal and there doesn't seem to be any other issues, it seems to point to the teeth doesn't it? hm

Comment: Well I'm note sure to be honest the tooth just looks a little out of place it doesn't seem discoloured or anything. She pressed down and the down a little with her finger and I myself have touched it and it doesn't seem to bother him. She said it only seems to be effecting that one tooth right now. Have you ever experienced something like this? Haru is my first pet and he has never been sick until now I'm just very confused. Thank you for taking the time to answer me by the way!

Answer (score 3):

Something you can try is to dampen her dry food. Now the issue with wetting dry food is bacteria will grow in it. Which is why dry food mixed with wet food needs to be eaten immediately and shouldn't be left out for hours. Try dampening some dry food to soften it. This should prevent diarrhea that canned food can give and will give her the same flavour experience that she is used to without any irritation on her tooth/gum.

The other thing you can try (and my cats love this) is buy small tins of tuna in oil. Drizzle some of the oil of the dry food with some of the tuna and see if this entices her to eat it. If it doesn't dry, then try dampening it. That way you will know whether it's her palate that has changed. or her tooth/gums causing her pain.

I have found that I would feed my cats a particular food for some time and they grew sick of it, so I experimented and tried different foods.

There are also recipes for indoors cats, fur ball and elderly cats. There are also some dry foods that are not as hard - no crunch - which may help her if there is pain.

Let us know how you get on and good luck.

Answer (score -2):

If you are truly desperate to get some nutrients into him, cooked dry oats on top of the little food he does eat.

So this link isn't working, I'm told, but Freshpet Wet food for cats is amazing, I swear by it! My 7-year-old Maine Coon cat loves it. It's the only brand of food she'll eat and it's extremely nutritious. That's my main suggestion.

Meow Mix Tender Centers is also a great dry food option. This one has softer centers in case the gingivitis is causing him mouth pain. It is also good for shoppers on a budget.

Lastly, take any brand of regular dry food and add a bit of chicken or bone broth and allow it to soak in to become softer. This should be eaten within half an hour to avoid bacteria growth.

Although this is years later I can only hope to help someone else with the same issues. Best of luck to you and your kitty and let us know if any tips were successful to help other kitten owners with the same issues.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your first link doesn't work and it's really bad to force people to click links to webshops. Please [edit] your answer and write the name of the cat foods directly in the answer. You can add links to shops or pictures of the products in addition to that, but in case a link goes bad your answer (in its current form) will technically be useless. If you're affiliated to any shop or pet food brand you promote here, you must clearly and unmistakably disclose this affiliation.

Comment: @Elmy all fixed! Thanks for your feedback :)